# What possible states does an Azure PSContainerGroup have

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am running a container on Azure Container Instances. In my code I use the PowerShell command [Get-AzContainerGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerinstance/get-azcontainergroup?view=azps-4.6.1) to find my running container. As a result I get the [PSContainerGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.containerinstance.models.pscontainergroup?view=azurerm-ps) class which has a property called State.

The type of the property is string, but to me it seems more like an enum that has certain possible values. I want to handle the container programmatically so a state property without a certain set of values is useless to me. What possible values for a state are there?

Answer (score 1):

It should be: Running, Terminated, Waiting, or Unknown. (Disclaimer: purely based on testing, may not be exhaustive list). Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-get-logs

I agree with you it could be better PSContainerGroup State property being an enum. You can raise feedback in User Voice https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances

Comment: I believe that the ACI states are something different than docker states, considering that at least Succeeded and Failed are valid states.

Comment: Updated the answer. When you see Succeeded and Failed, is it Container State or Provisioning State?